# Is $x/y$ is rational?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\mathbf{M}:=\big\{\ln(\sum_{i=0}^ka^{k-i}{b^i}:k\ge 1\big\}$, where $a,b\in (0,1)$ satisfy $a^n=b^m$ for some integers $m,n$.  I want to show it is impossible that $x/y$ is rational for all $x,y\in\mathbf{M}$. I think it is right, but cannot proof that.

Comment: What have you tried? As always, to prove something is not rational you should try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Does it help to rewrite the elements as $\ln\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b}$ (provided $a\ne b$)?

Comment: Counterexample: Consider the case $a=b$ (and so we can pick $m=n=42$), the elements $m_k\in M$ are just $m_k=\ln ((k+1)a^k)=k\ln a+\ln(k+1)$. Fix $ q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>2$. We can solve $m_2=qm_1$, (i.e., $2\ln a+\ln 3 =q(\ln a+\ln2)$) for $\ln a$, namely $\ln a=\frac{q\ln 2-\ln 3}{2-q}$. As this is negative, it leads to $a\in(0,1)$. --- Oh wait, you claim $\exists x,y\in M\frac xy\notin \Bbb Q$ and not $\forall x\ne y\in M\frac xy\notin \Bbb Q$, do you?